# In React app with google analytics, why some pages' avg. load time are zero?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

I am using `react-ga` to approach google analytics. And I found out some pages have the load time, but some not, like the following screen shot shows:
[image]

The pages without load time is actually no sample data. Many people mentioned it is because the smaple rate is too low. But in my case I don't think it is the reason because some pages with less pageviews still have the load time.

I guess it might because we truncated the url. Because `react` is single page app, we have to manually send the `pageview` event. When we send it, we truncated them in order to group them. e.g., the original link should be `/content/content-name/content-id`, we will truncated it to `/content`. Does anyone know about this, thanks? By the way, I am testing but it take time, and I want to know it eariler if possible. :)

Comment: Perhaps it's down to being an SPA, so the pages without load time aren't being directly accessed and are only visited once the app has loaded from a different URL.

Comment: In `ComponentDidMount` lifecycle, we manually send the `pageview` to ga: https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga#reactgapageviewpath